# Internal energy in phase transition

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, phase-transition

As I understand, in the process of state transition (fusion or vaporization) the temperature remains constant for the duration the process is happening. The internal energy is a function of only temperature, so does the internal energy not change?

Comment: $T=\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial S} \right)_{V,N}$ and **roughly** speaking it is proportional to the average energy per microstate of the system. In the process of phase transition, for example from liquid to gas, the internal energy grows, but simultaniously more microstates are accesable to the system, and so the ratio remains constant. You can see this principle manifistation in Clapeyron equation - $\frac{dP}{dT}=const=\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta v}$ the  change in entropy proportional to change in volume which is (roughly) proportional to the change in energy.

Comment: " Internal energy is a function of only temperature" is only valid for ideal gas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During a change of phase the temperature does not change, but the internal energy does.  The internal energy is the sum of the kinetic energy of the molecules and the chemical potential energy of the molecules.  During a change of phase, the average kinetic energy of the molecules stays the same (with the temperature), but the average potential energy changes.

For more information on this topic, do visit:

http://electron6.phys.utk.edu/101/CH7/phase_transitions.htm&ei=cJxiShax&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=364&ts=1436773479&sig=AKQ9UO84sBHgLYBnocfErpK9LfMYP6vfkQ

Comment: Thanks for the response.The link doesn't seem to work. Can you please redirect to some other resource.

Comment: Will you please try this one:                       http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://electron6.phys.utk.edu/101/CH7/phase_transitions.htm&ei=33wdAN6S&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=364&ts=1436788873&sig=AKQ9UO-s_2lJUcpA4hOlGe4hCvN0CCs_LA

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely true that internal energy is a function of time only. However it's not a strictly linear funtion. 
∆U=nC∆T is for small changes in temperature. Because C is not a constant but temperature dependant variable.
At phase changes, though temperature is constant, there is a gradual variation of C because of different degrees of freedom associated with different states.

Hope it helps.